# How to Design image icon with text in row for supporting all devices

Tags: android

How to design like this with suitable for all size of phones..need to design like this[image]

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if You Wrap your Image inside Linear Layout and Have Different Resolutions of image in Drawable's Folder, based on device it will Wrap image and Height

```
 <LinearLayout
    ...
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="4"
    ...>
          //for one Image similarly each image will have one LinearLayout
           <LinearLayout
           ...
           android:orientation="vertical"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:weightSum="4"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           ...
           >
             <ImageView>
              ...
              android:layout_height="0dp"
              android:layout_weight="3"
              ...
             </ImageView>

             <TextView>
             ...
             android:layout_height="0dp"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             ...
            </TextView>

         </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```